# Are Levites obligated to give foreleg, cheeks and maw

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, yoreh-deah, levites-leviyim, zeroa-lechayayim-keiva

According to Halacha are Levites obligated to give a kohen the [foreleg, cheeks, and maw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreleg,_cheeks_and_maw) of a Shechita’d animal? Or no, due to their unique lineage  are they exempt from the requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rambam Hilchot Bikkurim 9:8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_First_Fruits_and_other_Gifts_to_Priests_Outside_the_Sanctuary.9.8?lang=bi) writes that the law in this case is in doubt.
Therefore we don’t take these gifts from a Levite, but if a Kohen does take them we don’t make him return them.

[Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 61:23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.61.23?lang=bi) rules like Rambam, but a parenthetical comment there notes the dissenting opinion of Ran, who holds that we would make the Kohen return the gifts to the Levite.